# Tetragrammaton in paleo-Hebrew within Hebrew text of Tehilim

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, sefer-torah, archaeology, torah-writing

Many scrolls were found (in Qumran?) depicting a regular Hebrew scripture text with the Holy name written in paleo-Hebrew (כתב עברי), like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Judaism#/media/File:Tehilim_scroll.png):

[image]

What Talmudic explanation fits these findings, if this sort of writing is mentioned and what school is it associated with??

Comment: While we can speculate, there's no particular reason to expect a Talmudic ruling to fit these findings. The authors weren't followers of Rabbinic Judiasm.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sorry, I didn't mean ruling, I meant if this sort of writing is mentioned and what school is it associated with?

Comment: I once read an article (in Kulmus, I think) that they did this to prevent the scrolls from causing טומאת ידים since now it wasn't the real text. Or something along those lines.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Oh, interesting, does it follow that the name in P.H is not sacred?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Logically the two basic options are either they did it to prevent holiness of the name (because they thought only Ashuri counts) or to instill holiness in the name (because they thought only Ivri counts). There's no real way to know which. Nothing to do with Tumat Yadayim though, since the Mishna already says  the non-Perusim made fun of that (yadayim 4:6)

Comment: @DoubleAA - that article (I'll try look for it) discussed the arguments you're making; I wish I could remember the details.

Comment: @AlBerko I don't think that follows, depending on how you define "sacred". A printed chumash does not cause טומאת ידים, yet still requires some level of sacred treatment.

Comment: I'll wager the increase in holiness of the text was the object.  They've even found a Greek manuscript with the Name in Hebrew in it.