# Which tetragrammaton is more sacred - written in modern Hebrew or paleo-Hebrew font?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

In my previous question: [tetragrammaton-in-paleo-hebrew-within-hebrew-text-of-tehilim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106745/tetragrammaton-in-paleo-hebrew-within-hebrew-text-of-tehilim), there is evidence that p.H font was considered more sacred, as the Holy Name was written in it as opposed to the rest of the text.

What written Name is more sacred and is there a Halachic difference?